# como faço para usar push notification para mostra uma notificação para o usuário quando mudar qualquer no status no app Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

Olá! Sou novo na área e queria saber como eu faço para cria um método que possa notificar o usuário toda vez que tiver alguma mudança no status do pedido dele, pois estou criando um app de loja virtual e queria que o usuário soubesse quando tivesse alguma alteração no seu pedido.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OrderTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String orderId;

  OrderTile(this.orderId);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0, horizontal: 8.0),
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
              stream: Firestore.instance
                  .collection("orders")
                  .document(orderId)
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData)
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                else {
                  int status = snapshot.data["status"];

                  return Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        "Código do pedido: ${snapshot.data.documentID}",
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 4.0,
                      ),
                      Text(_buildProductsText(snapshot.data)),

                      //descrição do produto

                      SizedBox(
                        height: 4.0,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Status do Pedido:",
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 4.0,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          _buildCircle("1", "Preparação", status, 1),
                          Container(
                            height: 1.0,
                            width: 40.0,
                            color: Colors.grey[500],
                          ),
                          _buildCircle("2", "Transporte", status, 2),
                          Container(
                            height: 1.0,
                            width: 40.0,
                            color: Colors.grey[500],
                          ),
                          _buildCircle("3", "Entrega", status, 3),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  );
                }
              }),
        ));
  }

  String _buildProductsText(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    String text = "Descrição:\n";
    for (LinkedHashMap p in snapshot.data["products"]) {
      text +=
          "${p["quantity"]} x ${p["product"]["title"]} (R\$ ${p["product"]["price"].toStringAsFixed(2)})\n";
    }
    text += "Total: R\$ ${snapshot.data["totalPrice"].toStringAsFixed(2)}";
    return text;
  }

  Widget _buildCircle(
      String title, String subtitle, int status, int thisStatus) {
    Color backColor;
    Widget child;

    if (status < thisStatus) {
      backColor = Colors.grey[500];
      child = Text(
        title,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      );
    } else if (status == thisStatus) {
      backColor = Colors.blue;
      child = Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            title,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          CircularProgressIndicator(
            valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white),
          )
        ],
      );
    } else {
      backColor = Colors.green;
      child = Icon(
        Icons.check,
        color: Colors.white,
      );
    }

    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        CircleAvatar(
          radius: 20.0,
          backgroundColor: backColor,
          child: child,
        ),
        Text(subtitle)
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

No caso só queria que o usuário soubesse quando tivesse alguma alteração no firebase sobre o status de entrega.
Desde já agradeço a quem puder ajudar com esse projeto.

Comment: Como é novo no SOF, vou deixar uma dica: Já pesquisou sobre `push notification flutter` no goole? Recomendo que busque primeiro compreender como funciona em algum tutorial na internet e depois disso tente implementar no seu app. Depois de tentar implementar caso apareça um problema específico, pergunte sobre esse problema mostrando o que já fez e o que tentou. Como está sua pergunta ela recebe votos negativos pois mostra que não houve nenhum tipo de pesquisa de sua parte antes de vir até aqui.

Comment: Recomendo que estude sobre `OneSignal` para serviços de notificação. Existe outros mas ele é um dos mais utilizados no mercado e tem um passo a passo para implementação em projetos Flutter. Sem entender como é estruturado as notificações será complicado vc evoluir na sua implementação.

Comment: A notificação que eu desejo cria e somente quando eu faço mudança no status do cliente, tipo no app tem status de "preparação"  "transporte" e "entregue". No caso eu tenho outro aplicativo em conjunto que faz essas alterações e essas alterações são modificadas lá no firebase, eu só queria cria um método que eu possa avisar o cliente que seu status mudou sem eu ter que entra no firebase ou no onsignal para cria essa mensagem para o usuário. Eu já pesquisei e crie um método padrão do firebase o problema e que ele só notifica o que eu escrevo lá e não algo automático.

Answer (score -1):

Recomendo dar uma estudada sobre o OneSignal: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/flutter-sdk-setup

Sobre enviar as notificações push ao alterar alguma info no app, você vai precisar ter o PlayerID do usuário, se você utiliza o próprio flutter+dart pro backend do seu app basta vc criar as funções que vai disparar as push utilizando o playerid, neste link que te mandei voce vai encontrar todos os passo de como obter o player id e como fazer os envios de push diretamente para o usuário.

Comment: muito obrigado vou olha agora.